# Getting dependency injected services in ASP MVC Core outside of request pipeline in muti-tenant app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

Having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this.  This is a multi tenant ASP MVC Core 3.1 app and the current means of resolving the user's current tenant is via claims in the cookie.  I have the following in the `startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddScoped<ITenantResolver, TenantResolver>();
services.AddScoped(p => p.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.GetTenant());
```

and the following middleware registered in the `Configure` method:

```
app.UseMiddleware<TenantResolutionMiddleware>();
```

The process is that the middleware resolves the tenant (using the `TenantResolver`) and then sets it in the `HttpContext`.  The `GetTenant()` extension method on the `HttpContext` returns the tenant to the services.  Depending on the selected tenant different connections strings are used and therefore the `EFCore` `DbContext` is linked to a different database.  Really the only difference when different tenants are selected are the `DbContext` and the `Tenant` object;

That all works, but what I need to be able to do is use the services outside of the request pipeline, say in a hangfire background job or in an ancillary project I need services to report on different databases in an application that does not have a request pipeline.

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
foreach(var tenant in Tenants) 
{
     // set the tenant
     // get a service provider for that tenant and use those services
}
```

I know I need to be able to 'set the tenant' outside of the tenant resolution system but my mind is stuck in the request stack.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: So the logic to resolve a Tenant is based on the claims using string values? What collection of string values maps to your collection of Tenants? This is all independent of the HttpRequest which is just a mechanism to persist the string value in claims via cookies. I'm assuming `HttpContext.User` is being used to get access to the claims in your middleware but that's all syntactic sugar to get to the string value.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `HttpContext.User` to get the claims, there is a claim 'currentTenant' with a value of the tenant id.  There are also claims as to whether they have access that is used in the auth section but for DI I just care about 'currentTenant'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your services still use dependency injection? You can create an ITenantResolver that lets you explicitly set the tenant:

```
class TenantResolver : ITenantResolver
{
    // Not sure what type 'Tenant' is, but you can change it to suit
    public string Tenant { get; set; }

    string GetTenant() => Tenant;
}
```

Then in your service's main execution loop:

```
var factory = services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

foreach (var tenant in Tenants) 
{
    using (var scope = factory.CreateScope())
    {
        scope.Services.GetService<TenantResolver>().Tenant = tenant;
        
        // Use scope.Services to resolve services using the current tenant
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are a bunch of services that are dependant on the resolved tenant and the corresponding DbContrext.  Seeing your answer I think, of course, I just need another TenantResolver and in a sense a new 'dependency tree' (forgive if that's not the correct term).  I am guessing that's what the 'scope' is in your example.  Thinking I need to create a new scope outside of the request pipeline.  Would I need to re-register all the services in that scope?  I'll look at that, thanks.

Comment: Creating scopes is a separate process to registering services. You register services once, at startup, then any scopes you create will use the registered services